# $\begin{pmatrix}A_1&A_{12}\\0&A_2\end{pmatrix}$ is similar to $\begin{pmatrix}A_1&0\\0&A_2\end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices, similar-matrices

> Let $A_1$ be an $m \times m$ matrix and $A_2$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. Let the respective characteristic polynomials $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ be relative prime, i.e., $(f_1, f_2) = 1$. Show that $$\begin{pmatrix}A_1&A_{12}\\0&A_2\end{pmatrix}$$ is similar to $$\begin{pmatrix}A_1&0\\0&A_2\end{pmatrix}$$

---

If $A_1,A_2$ is diagnoal in the complex field, then $A_1,B_1$ has no common root. It seems not so difficult. What about general filed?

Comment: $A_{12}$ is any other matrix (with appropriate dimensions), right?

Comment: Maybe the Bezout identity $f_1 g_1 + f_2 g_2=1$ would be useful?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yes.

Comment: The field non being algebraically closed isn't an issue because you can always pass to the algebraic closure.  And by conjugating by a block diagonal matrix, you can assume that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are in Jordan normal form.  The difficulty is whether there are repeated eigenvalues, where you cannot tell diagonalizability (or whether two matrices are similar) strictly from their characteristic polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For brevity I will write $A_1,A_{12}$ and $A_2$ as $A,B$ and $C$ respectively. Consider the equation
$$
\pmatrix{A&B\\ 0&C}\pmatrix{I_m&X\\ 0&I_n}=\pmatrix{I_m&X\\ 0&I_n}\pmatrix{A&0\\ 0&C}.
$$
This is equivalent to the Sylvester equation $AX-XC=-B$. Define $L:X\mapsto AX-XC$. If we can prove that [$L$ is nonsingular](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4116255), then $L(X)=-B$ is solvable and we are done.

To prove that $L$ is nonsingular, we want to show that $L(X)=0$ has only the trivial solution. Suppose $L(X)=0$. Then $AX=XC,\,A^2X=XC^2$, so on and so forth. In turn, $p(A)X=Xp(C)$ for every polynomial $p$. Take $p$ as the characteristic polynomial of $C$. Then $p(C)=0$ but $p(A)$ is nonsingular because $p$ is relatively prime to the characteristic polynomial of $A$. Therefore $X=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the basis of the space with respect to which this is the matrix be $u_1,\dots,u_m,w_1,\dots,w_n$, and let $U$ be the span of $u_1,\dots, u_m$, $W$ the span of $w_1,\dots,w_n$.

We are discussing a linear map $\alpha: U\oplus W\to U\oplus W$ where the matrix of $\alpha|U$ is $A_1$, and the matrix of the induced map $\bar{\alpha}$ on the quotient $U\oplus W / U$ is $A_2$.

We are given that the characteristic polynomials of $A_1$, $A_2$ namely $f_1$ and $f_2$ are coprime.

The characteristic polynomial $f$ of $\alpha$ is of course $f_1 f_2$, which annihilates $\alpha$, so we have in the usual way by the coprimeness of $f_1$and $f_2$ that
$$
U\oplus W=\ker f(\alpha)=\ker f_1(\alpha)\oplus \ker f_2(\alpha),
$$
and this latter decomposition is into $\alpha$-invariant subspaces.
[This is where @lysarus hint is useful.]

Let us identify $\ker f_1(\alpha)$. The  matrix of $f_1(\alpha)$ on the basis $u_1,\dots, u_m,w_1,\dots,w_m$ is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}f_1(A_1) & *\\O &f_1(A_2)\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}O & *\\O &f_1(A_2)\end{pmatrix}.
$$
As $f_1$ and $f_2$ are coprime (and $f_2$ annihilates $A_2$) we have that $f_1(A_2)$  must be non-singular. Hence we have that $\ker f_1(\alpha)=U$.

The action of $\alpha$ on the invariant subspace $\ker f_1(\alpha)=U$ is given by $A_1$. Suppose the action of $\alpha$ on the invariant subspace $\ker f_2(\alpha)$ is given by a matrix $B$. Then the action on the quotient $U\oplus W/U=\ker f_1(\alpha)\oplus\ker f_2(\alpha)/\ker f_1(\alpha)$ is given by the matrix $B$ - but we know it is given by $A_2$, so that after a change of basis in $\ker f_2(\alpha)$ we may assume that the matrix of $\alpha$ on $\ker f_2(\alpha)$ is $A_2$.

We have therefore shown that with respect to a suitable basis the matrix of $\alpha$ is $\begin{pmatrix}A_1 & O\\O &A_2\end{pmatrix}$ as required.